# Google App Engine - Datastore - GQL Query

Tags: google-app-engine, gqlquery

```
class ProjectCategory(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty("Category name", required = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Project(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty("Name", required = True)
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(ProjectCategory)  
    description = db.TextProperty("Description", required = True)
    #file_name = db.StringProperty("File name", required = True)
    file = db.BlobProperty("Image")

    whenstarted = db.DateTimeProperty("Start time")
    whenended = db.DateTimeProperty("End Time")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

How to get all Projects where category is CatName

hmm

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Project WHERE category = :1", "CatName")
```

don't work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query does not work because you are passing a `"CatName"` string instead of a `ProjectCategory` instance's key.

Retrieve your desired `ProjectCategory` entity from Datastore first with:

```
pjc =  GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProjectCategory WHERE name = :1", "CatName").get()
```

then use it as parameter in the query like this:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Project WHERE category = :1", pjc.key())
```

---

A second approach is to use the implicit `modelname_set` Property of the `ProjectCategory` instance:

```
pjc =  GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProjectCategory WHERE name = :1", "CatName").get()

pjc.project_set.fetch(10) #should contains some CatName projects
```